# How to update angular project from 5 to 7

Tags: angular, webpack, angular5, angular7

I am trying to update my project from angular 5 to angular 7.
For this first is update @angular/cli gloabaly and locally
then I installed @angular/cli locally then update ng module and other related commands.

Now, I check my ng --version it is showing me angular 7, but my project is not running its always throwing below error:
[image]

```
Below is my script in package.json file:

"scripts": {
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --port=9000 -- 
   content-base wwwroot/",
   "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --progress",
   "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack  --progress"
 }
```

Comment: Did you follow the procedure given in [this guide](https://update.angular.io/)?

Comment: @ConnorsFan, I follow angulay official link: https://update.angular.io

Comment: your compiler version is seems old, try again by updating your angular dependencies manually in package.json

Comment: ng update --all ?

Comment: @RobertoManfreda, thanks for your attention, but still I am getting same error, I am using backend with asp.net core.

Comment: Try to execute these commands in sequence:
npm update --dev;
npm install --save; 
npm outdated;(if npm outdated returns some hint try to execute the recommended commands).
ng update --all;

Answer (score 5):

Steps of updating angular latest version 7:

1 ) You need to update your angular cli.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean or npm cache verify 
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

(c.f https://cli.angular.io/)

2) You need to upgrade your project version as per suggestion of angular update guide. Angular update guide website link [Angular version upgrade guide website link (Click here)](https://update.angular.io/)

3) On this website select your older version and your desired latest version after that click on 'Show me how to update'

4) After click on this button website provide a number of steps. You need to follow this step to upgrade your Angular version

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in 2020, make the following steps:

```sh
npm uninstall -g angular-cli

npm cache clean 

npm cache verify 

npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.6(or the specific version of Angular 7)
```

Check your package-lock.json.  It should be working for you. If it still doesn't work, use the following commands:

```sh
ng update @angular/cli

ng update @angular/core

npm audit fix

npm start
```

Also check https://update.angular.io/.